# Geom_text Value overlapping

Tags: r, geom-bar, geom-text

I trying to create a Pie chart, but the value is overlapping each other.

Sample Data:

```
City_Area   Age   Spending
   A       0-15    100
   A       15-30   400
   B       0-15    200
   B       15-30   300
```

Here my code:

```
CA = filter(City_Area == 'A') %>% group_by(City_Area,Age,Spending)

ggplot(CA, aes(x="",y = Spending, fill = Age)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')+ coord_polar("y") + theme_void() + geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(round((..count..)/sum(..count..),2)),y= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",position=position_stack(0.5))
```

[image: PieValueStack]

Here without coord_polar

[image: Barchart without coord_polar]

[Using Rui Barradas code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WHBj.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(CA)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(CA, 20))`.

Comment: This is one of my school project and currently trying to create a Pie chart, I tried looking online using geom_text and this line of geom_text code is the closest and I am not sure what's wrong. There are a total of 7 age group actually, the sample data is just a rough idea. @RuiBarradas

Comment: what do you mean y = ..count.. , I still unclear about geom_text functions

Comment: Done, see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The data preparation code seems to be wrong and so does the plotting code.

First, prepare the data. The main thing to do is to get rid of the dollar signs. I will do that with `sub`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

CA2 <- CA %>% 
  mutate(Spending = as.numeric(sub("\\$", "", Spending))) %>%
  filter(City_Area == 'A')
```

In the question there is a `group_by` line but for this example it is not needed.

Now the plot.

```
ggplot(CA2, aes(x = "", y = Spending, fill = Age)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  coord_polar("y") + 
  theme_void() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Spending/sum(Spending), 2)), 
            position = position_stack(0.5))
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
CA <- read.table(text = "
City_Area   Age   Spending
A       0-15    100$
A       15-30   400$
B       0-15    200$
B       15-30   300$
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Apparently, it created a big black circle, I have added a picture of the pie chart using your code.  Is there any way I can contact you privately, as I cannot show my full code here, the dataset is quite big even with sample data is still hard to explain. I can show you my whole code privately if you don't mind.